# Outputting a reply to a comment

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have add comments to the article, here are all the fields

```
Schema::create('article_comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->bigIncrements('id');
   $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');
   $table->foreign('article_id')
         ->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->string('name');
   $table->string('email');
   $table->text('text');
   $table->string('date');

   $table->unsignedBigInteger('comment_id')->nullable();
   $table->foreign('comment_id')
         ->references('id')->on('article_comments')->onDelete('set null');

   $table->timestamps();
});
```

I have 2 blocks of comments, one regular and the second answer to it. The only difference between them is the different classes

This is how I bring them out

Normal comment

```
<div class="comment-list">
    @foreach($article_comments as $article_comment)
    <div class="comment-list__item">
        <div class="item-card">
            <div class="item-card__header">
                <div class="item-card__title">
                    <div class="label">
                        {!! $article_comment->name !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {!! date('d F Y', strtotime($article_comment->date)) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-card__content">
                {!! $article_comment->text !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

The reply to him

```
<div class="comment-sub-list">
    <div class="comment-sub-list__item">
        <div class="item-card">
            <div class="item-card__header">
                <div class="item-card__title">
                    <div class="label">
                        {!! $article_comment->name !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="data">
                        {!! date('d F Y', strtotime($article_comment->date)) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item-card__content">
                {!! $article_comment->text !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the `comment_id` field is filled in, then this will be the answer to the comment with this ID, but I can't implement it

I'm trying to type-check for the presence of the `comment_id` field and display this comment

```
$articleCommentsReply = $article_comments->where('comment_id', $article_comment->comment_id)
->whereNotNull('comment_id')
->first();
```

But in the end, this comment is displayed twice, and one of them is the answer to it

Comment: In `articleCommentsReply` you just find the record, add `->get()` or `->first()` to end of your query: `$article_comments->where('comment_id', $article_comment->comment_id)->first();`

Comment: @Miladpegah yes, it works, but what I came up with is not correct anyway, it finds and displays comments in which `comment_id = null`, but it is only necessary where there is a value

Comment: have added an answer. hope it solves the problem you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on my understanding of your question here is what you can do to achieve it.

Here I have assumed the article might have many comments and each comment might have zero or many answers to it with maximum one level recursive.

But You can change `answers` relationship to just `answer` by defining it as `hasOne` relationship if you want and instead of using get() can also use first(). Advantage with this `hasMany` method is that it will work for both single and multiple related models if you keep it this way.

You can add `answers` recursive relation to `ArticleComment` model

```
//in ArticleComment.php
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ArticleComment::class, 'comment_id', 'id');
}
```

I assume you already have this relationship defined, if not add this `comments` relationship to `Article` model.

```
//in Article.php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ArticleComment::class, 'article_id', 'id');
}
```

Now you can use following query to fetch the articles with `comments`. If an answer for that comment exist it will return inside `answers` relation. If it is just the comment it will return just the comment inside the `comments` relation and `answers` will be an empty array.

In the example query below we are looking for comments(with its replies if it has any) of article with id 1. The said article has 2 comments. the first comment has 3 answers to it and second comment does not have any.

```
$query = Article::where('id', 1)->with(['comments' => function($q) {
            $q->whereNull('comment_id')->with('answers');
        }]);

$output = $query->get()->toArray();
```

Here is how the output of this query would look like.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "article 1"
    "comments": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "article_id": 1,
        "name": "a1q1",
        "email": "***",
        "text": "Article 1 Comment 1",
        "date": "2021-11-22 16:52:11",
        "comment_id": null
        "answers": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "article_id": 1,
            "name": "a1q1a1",
            "email": "***",
            "text": "Answer 1 to Article 1 Comment 1",
            "date": "2021-11-22 16:52:11",
            "comment_id": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 6,
            "article_id": 1,
            "name": "a1q1a1",
            "email": "***",
            "text": "Answer 2 to Article 1 Comment 1",
            "date": "2021-11-22 16:52:11",
            "comment_id": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "article_id": 1,
        "name": "a1q2",
        "email": "***",
        "text": "Article 1 Comment 2",
        "date": "2021-11-22 16:52:11",
        "comment_id": null,
        "answers": [
          
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

> Note: I think the above method is more efficient if you want to
> display the article,comments and replies in the same page as it does
> only one query.

If the answer you are looking for is how to separately check and get specific comments you can use following queries.

just the replies to comment id 1

```
$repliesToCommentOnly = ArticleComment::where('comment_id', $articleComment->id)
    ->get()->toArray();
```

output

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "article_id": 1,
    "name": "a1q1a1",
    "email": "***",
    "text": "Answer 1 to Article 1 Comment 1",
    "date": "2021-11-22 16:52:11",
    "comment_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "article_id": 1,
    "name": "a1q1a1",
    "email": "***",
    "text": "Answer 2 to Article 1 Comment 1",
    "date": "2021-11-22 16:52:11",
    "comment_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z"
  }
]
```

article comment with its replies

```
$commentWitItsReplies = ArticleComment::where('id', 1)->with('answers')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

output

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "article_id": 1,
    "name": "a1q1",
    "email": "***",
    "text": "Article 1 Comment 1",
    "date": "2021-11-22 16:52:11",
    "comment_id": null,
    "created_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z",
    "answers": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "article_id": 1,
        "name": "a1q1a1",
        "email": "***",
        "text": "Answer 1 to Article 1 Comment 1",
        "date": "2021-11-22 16:52:11",
        "comment_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "article_id": 1,
        "name": "a1q1a1",
        "email": "***",
        "text": "Answer 2 to Article 1 Comment 1",
        "date": "2021-11-22 16:52:11",
        "comment_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-22T16:52:11.000000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
$articleCommentsReply = $article_comments
    ->where('comment_id', $article_comment->comment_id)
    ->first();
```

You are missing the output of your query (in that case `->first()`)

That will return you a single collection and then you should be able to access your property like you attempted.

Also an update based on your comment since you are getting nullable comment_ids you can also filter them out by extending your query to :

```php
$articleCommentsReply = $article_comments
    ->where('comment_id', $article_comment->comment_id)
    ->whereNotNull('comment_id')
    ->first();
```

Comment: yes, it works, but what I came up with is not correct anyway, it finds and displays comments in which `comment_id = null`, but it is only necessary where there is a value

Comment: @chu I updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: works, but now you still need to somehow do it so that it was a reply to a comment with the current comment_id, and now it just creates the same comment 2 times, and one of them is an answer

Comment: I am sorry but i am trying to help you here but you start sounding a bit rude for no particular reason.... "you accidentally have no idea how to fix it?" what is that even supposed to mean? Also in your code there is no query for creating a comment, the query only retrives a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I was not trying to be rude to you, I just wanted to ask if you have any thoughts on this matter